# What is the average distance between electron 'shells' in an atom? Or between the innermost shell and the nucleus?

Tags: energy, electrons, electronic-configuration, atomic-structure, atomic-radius

Somehow, I've never come across any mention of the actual, physical distances between, say the 1s and 2s shells in an atom, whether large or small....

I know that p, d and f (and g?) shells are oddly shaped, and that quantum mechanics tells us that there is only a probability of a particle being found in a particular location, etc, etc....

I am also curious as to the (average) distance between a uranium nucleus and its 1s electrons....

Comment: Since the 1s orbital is radially symmetric, the 'average' is r=0.

Comment: @JonCuster That would be the average position but not the average distance from the center.

Comment: The shells are overlapping; in essence they occupy the same space. Your "etc, etc..." can't be trivially blown off as something unimportant. It begs the question, why would you care to attempt to compute something like this, and, what is it exactly you would be computing? Take a swarm of flies and a swarm of bees centered on the same pot of honey, then compute the actual physical distance between them. Where do you start?

Comment: @NisargBhavsar - indeed, but perhaps they can find the homework answers on the internet now...

Comment: Actually, this is one of those times where the good old Bohr model isn't that bad for providing insight. The 1s orbital roughly scales with 1/Z, so that would be 1 for hydrogen and 1/92 for Uranium in units of the Bohr radius (53pm and 0.58pm) if we ignore relativistic effects.

Comment: Also, a related question here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/136453/how-to-compare-size-of-subshells

Answer (score 3):

> I am also curious as to the (average) distance between a uranium nucleus and its 1s electrons

I am sorry to say but that is computationally too hard to accomplish. Just the sheer number of interactions will overcomplicate the equation. For such big atomic numbers, relavistic effects will also have to be taken into consideration.

But this calculation can be done for a hydrogen atom as the number of interactions are limited and the ignoring the relavistic effects doesn't affect the end result much.

Wavefunction of the hydrogen $\mathrm{1s}$ electron is<sup>[[1]](https://chem.libretexts.org/@go/page/41377)</sup>:

$$\psi=\frac{1}{\sqrt{π}}\left(\frac{1}{a_0}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}e^{-\frac{r}{a_0}}$$

Now the probability of finding an electron at an distance $r$ from the nucleus is $\psi^2\left(4πr^2\mathrm dr\right)$. This is because $\psi^2$ is the probability density and $4πr^2\mathrm dr$ is the volume in consideration.

$$
\begin{align}
\psi^2&=\frac{1}{πa_0^3}e^{-\frac{2r}{a_0}}\\
\psi^2\left(4πr^2\mathrm dr\right)&=4\frac{r^2}{a_0^3}e^{-\frac{2r}{a_0}}\mathrm dr\\
\mathrm dP(r)&=4\frac{r^2}{a_0^3}e^{-\frac{2r}{a_0}}\mathrm dr\\
\end{align}
$$

Now mathematically,

$$
\begin{align}
\bar r&= \int_0^\infty r\mathrm dP(r)\\
\bar r&= \int_0^\infty 4\frac{r^3}{{a_0}^3}e^{-\frac{2r}{a_0}}\mathrm dr\\
\end{align}
$$

Now using integral by parts,

$$
\begin{align}
\bar r&= \left[-2\frac{r^3}{a_0^2}e^{-\frac{2r}{a_0}} -3\frac{r^2}{a_0}e^{-\frac{2r}{a_0}} - 3re^{-\frac{2r}{a_0}} - \frac{3}{2}a_0e^{-\frac{2r}{a_0}}\right]_0^\infty\\
\bar r&= \left(0 + 0 + 0 + 0\right) - \left(0 + 0 + 0 - \frac{3}{2}a_0\right) \\
\bar r&= \frac{3}{2}a_0≈\pu{79.35 pm}\\
\end{align}
$$

Therefore an electron in $\mathrm{1s}$ orbital of an hydrogen atom is at an average distance of $\pu{79.35 pm}$ from the nucleus.

As you would have noticed, things got complicated even when we started with the wavefunction already ready. Finding the wavefunction for atoms like uranium is very tedious as well.

Still there has been a research<sup>[[2]](https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1958.0178)</sup> that you might be interested in, which has approximated the wavefunctions for the $\mathrm{6d^6}$, $\mathrm{5f^26d^27s^2}$, $\mathrm{5f^46d^2}$ and $\mathrm{5f^6}$ configurations of metallic uranium.

---

**References:**

<sup>[(1)](https://chem.libretexts.org/@go/page/41377) Libretexts. 11.10: The Schrödinger wave equation for the hydrogen atom
https://chem.libretexts.org/@go/page/41377 (accessed Jun 29, 2021).</sup>

<sup>[(2)](https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1958.0178) Ridley, E. C. A Qualitative Investigation of the Wave Functions of Metallic Uranium. *Proc. R. Soc. Lond.* **1958**, *247* (1249), 199–213.</sup>